# Currency Convertor in jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, currency

I am making a android app with the help of JQuery Mobile. In these app i want to convert the currency what the user want it should check it globally wht is the currency rate on that time and that day

In HTML5:-

```
 <label for="amount">Convert this amount:</label>
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="" />
 <div class="data">
    <label for="fromCurrency">From this currency:</label>
    <select name="fromCurrency" id="fromCurrency">
      <option selected="" value="EUR">Euro - EUR</option>
      <option value="USD">United States Dollars - USD</option>
      <option value="GBP">United Kingdom Pounds - GBP</option>
      <option value="CAD">Canada Dollars - CAD</option>
      <option value="AUD">Australia Dollars - AUD</option>
      <option value="JPY">India Rupees - JPY</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="data">
    <label for="toCurrency">To this currency:</label>
    <select name="toCurrency" id="toCurrency">
      <option value="USD">United States Dollars - USD</option>
      <option value="GBP">United Kingdom Pounds - GBP</option>
      <option value="CAD">Canada Dollars - CAD</option>
      <option value="AUD">Australia Dollars - AUD</option>
      <option value="JPY">Japan Yen - JPY</option>
      <option value="INR">India Rupees - INR</option>
    </select>
</div>

    <input type="button" name="convert" id="convert" value="Convert" />

    <div id="results"></div>
```

In JQuery:-

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#convert').click(function(){
         var amount = $('#amount').val();
         var from = $('#fromCurrency').val();
         var to = $('#toCurrency').val();
         var dataString = "amount=" + amount + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to;
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q="+dataString,
               data: dataString,
               success: function(data){
                $('#results').show();
                $('#results').html(data);
               }
            });
         });
     });
```

What the mistake i did it here it is not coming

Please help me out

Inside the head tag i have use  following script

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Sheetal in console it is showing  Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @Sheetal after hosting there no error is showing

Comment: try this `"http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q="+amount+from+"=?"+to`

Comment: @Sheetal if other process is there plz help me out and one more thing in php it is running f9 but i want it in jquery

Comment: @TryingTobemyself it is showing XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=20EUR=?USD. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. error in console

Comment: change the line of code   var dataString = amount + from + "=?" + to;

Comment: @Sheetal its not working

Comment: @Sheetal i think it is in problm in date:datestring

Comment: @TryingTobemyself i think it is in problm in date:datestring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes the working code:

```
 $('#convert').click(function(){
         var amount = $('#amount').val();
         var from = $('#fromCurrency').val();

         var to = $('#toCurrency').val();
         var dataString = from + "&to=" + to + "&q=" + amount;

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",   
            url: "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=" + dataString,
            success: function(data){
              alert(JSON.stringify(data));
              $('#results').show();
              $('#results').html(data.v);
            },error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: wht will be the date:datestring or rather then something else

Comment: please check out wht script i have used inside the head tag

Comment: kk i have to create own Restful json web service

Comment: kkk i will try if i get success then i will inform u r u in FB

Comment: please help me out i have generated app_id in openexchangerate.org after that how i cn implement it in script

Comment: Check the updated code there is another JSON(P) API http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=1 based on the Google API.

Comment: wht is data.v u have use in $('#results').html(data.v);

Comment: It is the converted value, i have put alert, what the web services gives back, you can dump anything that you want in your results element, i am just helping out, please close this and mark the answer if it helps. Also requesting please remove other unnecessary comments you have posted, other users cannot benefit if there are so many comments.

Comment: but i m nt getting in browser